# Does barman require continuous execution of receive-wal on a slot for streaming replication to work?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, write-ahead-logging, barman

I am new to barman and am trying to implement barman on my server. I have followed each and every step as mentioned in the barman [docs](http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.4/). Everything works fine till the receive-wal command in running in foreground. Once it stops the wal files from my main db get archived in done state in /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_xlog/archive_status but do not get deleted. This also happens when I take a complete backup onto barman and stop barman server. The replication slot used for streaming replication is still active in the main db.

- Is it necessary to continuously run receive-wal command on the barman server?
- Should I always remove the replication slot from the main db once the backup is complete?
- What happens when a pg_restore command is run on the main db being replicated? ( In my case the pg_xlog files are being created at an insane rate thus creating large number of checkpoints. Eventually wal files only get created but are not deleted. What exactly should be done in this scenario? )